# Changing lots of code in Xcode without ruining an already functioning application

Tags: c++, xcode

I've been using Xcode for about a year now.  I'm a novice programmer with just a tad bit of knowledge in C++.  I've never dug into the functionality of Xcode because my classes were so rudimentary that they didn't focus on anything but building simple command line applications.  On my own, I've begun to dig into source control and using local and github repositories, in order to keep track of my changes.  My question is, what exactly should I do if I want to change a large chunk of code, without ruining my already working code?  I'm still a bit confused on all the options, like branches and whatnot.  I have a command line application that is a simple contact application that I'm working on.  It uses a structure that holds First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, Address (using vectors) and age (using int).  I wrote the whole program to work with the age as an Int, but I'd like to change it to a vector (so I can insert N/A when the user doesn't enter an age, which is what I did with the other fields).  So, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to go about making this change without totally ruining my previous code, in case it doesn't work out.  Should i just make an incremental commit and roll back if necessary?  Or use a branch?  Just looking for some guidance here.

Application is here if case anyone is interested.  Its rough and not finished.  I am only making it to practice working with vectors:  https://github.com/JosephTLyons/Joseph-Lyons-Contact-Book-Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit more research into branches and it turns out, that's exactly what I needed to use.